# A script that loads an image at random from an array without repeating any until all have been viewed

Tags: javascript

I am running a script that loads an image from an array at random each time the page is refreshed. An undesirable feature of this script, and every other script like it that I have seen online, is that though there are over 100 images in the array, it often loads the same image a number of times before all of the images in the array have been viewed.

I would like to alter the script to prevent the same image from being called twice before all of the images in the array have been viewed. If an entirely different approach than the one I have taken here is preferable, please let me know. Also, my understanding of javascript is shakey so a thorough explanation of how to correct this issue would be most helpful.

Thanks in advance

Here is the page source:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!--[if IE]><link href="css/ie-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"><![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var xoxo = new Array(); // Array to hold filenames

            xoxo[0] = "images/portrait/fpo/01.jpg"
            xoxo[1] = "images/portrait/fpo/02.jpg"
            xoxo[2] = "images/portrait/fpo/03.jpg"
            xoxo[3] = "images/portrait/fpo/04.jpg"
            xoxo[4] = "images/portrait/fpo/05.jpg"
            xoxo[5] = "images/portrait/fpo/06.jpg"
            xoxo[6] = "images/portrait/fpo/07.jpg"
            xoxo[7] = "images/portrait/fpo/08.jpg"
            xoxo[8] = "images/portrait/fpo/09.jpg"
            xoxo[9] = "images/portrait/fpo/10.jpg"
            xoxo[10] = "images/portrait/fpo/11.jpg"
            xoxo[11] = "images/portrait/fpo/12.jpg"
            xoxo[12] = "images/portrait/fpo/13.jpg"
            xoxo[13] = "images/portrait/fpo/14.jpg"
            xoxo[14] = "images/portrait/fpo/15.jpg"
            xoxo[15] = "images/portrait/fpo/16.jpg"
            xoxo[16] = "images/portrait/fpo/17.jpg"
            xoxo[17] = "images/portrait/fpo/18.jpg"
            xoxo[18] = "images/portrait/fpo/19.jpg"
            xoxo[19] = "images/portrait/fpo/20.jpg"
            xoxo[20] = "images/portrait/fpo/21.jpg"
            xoxo[21] = "images/portrait/fpo/22.jpg"
            xoxo[22] = "images/portrait/fpo/23.jpg"
            xoxo[23] = "images/portrait/fpo/24.jpg"
            xoxo[24] = "images/portrait/fpo/25.jpg"
            xoxo[25] = "images/portrait/fpo/26.jpg"
            xoxo[26] = "images/portrait/fpo/27.jpg"
            xoxo[27] = "images/portrait/fpo/28.jpg"
            xoxo[28] = "images/portrait/fpo/29.jpg"
            xoxo[29] = "images/portrait/fpo/30.jpg"
            xoxo[30] = "images/portrait/fpo/31.jpg"
            xoxo[31] = "images/portrait/fpo/32.jpg"
            xoxo[32] = "images/portrait/fpo/33.jpg"
            xoxo[33] = "images/portrait/fpo/34.jpg"
            xoxo[34] = "images/portrait/fpo/35.jpg"
            xoxo[35] = "images/portrait/fpo/36.jpg"
            xoxo[36] = "images/portrait/fpo/37.jpg"
            xoxo[37] = "images/portrait/fpo/38.jpg"
            xoxo[38] = "images/portrait/fpo/39.jpg"
            xoxo[39] = "images/portrait/fpo/40.jpg"
            xoxo[40] = "images/portrait/fpo/41.jpg"
            xoxo[41] = "images/portrait/fpo/42.jpg"
            xoxo[42] = "images/portrait/fpo/43.jpg"
            xoxo[43] = "images/portrait/fpo/44.jpg"
            xoxo[44] = "images/portrait/fpo/45.jpg"
            xoxo[45] = "images/portrait/fpo/46.jpg"
            xoxo[46] = "images/portrait/fpo/47.jpg"
            xoxo[47] = "images/portrait/fpo/48.jpg"
            xoxo[48] = "images/portrait/fpo/49.jpg"
            xoxo[49] = "images/portrait/fpo/50.jpg"
            xoxo[50] = "images/portrait/fpo/51.jpg"
            xoxo[51] = "images/portrait/fpo/52.jpg"
            xoxo[52] = "images/portrait/fpo/53.jpg"
            xoxo[53] = "images/portrait/fpo/54.jpg"
            xoxo[54] = "images/portrait/fpo/55.jpg"
            xoxo[55] = "images/portrait/fpo/56.jpg"
            xoxo[56] = "images/portrait/fpo/57.jpg"
            xoxo[57] = "images/portrait/fpo/58.jpg"
            xoxo[58] = "images/portrait/fpo/59.jpg"
            xoxo[59] = "images/portrait/fpo/60.jpg"
            xoxo[60] = "images/portrait/fpo/61.jpg"
            xoxo[61] = "images/portrait/fpo/62.jpg"
            xoxo[62] = "images/portrait/fpo/63.jpg"
            xoxo[63] = "images/portrait/fpo/64.jpg"
            xoxo[64] = "images/portrait/fpo/65.jpg"
            xoxo[65] = "images/portrait/fpo/66.jpg"
            xoxo[66] = "images/portrait/fpo/67.jpg"
            xoxo[67] = "images/portrait/fpo/68.jpg"
            xoxo[68] = "images/portrait/fpo/69.jpg"
            xoxo[69] = "images/fashion/fpo/01.jpg"
            xoxo[70] = "images/fashion/fpo/02.jpg"
            xoxo[71] = "images/fashion/fpo/03.jpg"
            xoxo[72] = "images/fashion/fpo/04.jpg"
            xoxo[73] = "images/fashion/fpo/05.jpg"
            xoxo[74] = "images/fashion/fpo/06.jpg"
            xoxo[75] = "images/fashion/fpo/07.jpg"
            xoxo[76] = "images/fashion/fpo/08.jpg"
            xoxo[77] = "images/fashion/fpo/09.jpg"
            xoxo[78] = "images/fashion/fpo/10.jpg"
            xoxo[79] = "images/fashion/fpo/11.jpg"
            xoxo[80] = "images/fashion/fpo/12.jpg"
            xoxo[81] = "images/fashion/fpo/13.jpg"
            xoxo[82] = "images/fashion/fpo/14.jpg"
            xoxo[83] = "images/fashion/fpo/15.jpg"
            xoxo[84] = "images/fashion/fpo/16.jpg"
            xoxo[85] = "images/fashion/fpo/17.jpg"
            xoxo[86] = "images/fashion/fpo/18.jpg"
            xoxo[87] = "images/fashion/fpo/19.jpg"
            xoxo[88] = "images/fashion/fpo/20.jpg"
            xoxo[89] = "images/fashion/fpo/21.jpg"
            xoxo[90] = "images/fashion/fpo/22.jpg"
            xoxo[91] = "images/fashion/fpo/23.jpg"
            xoxo[92] = "images/fashion/fpo/24.jpg"
            xoxo[93] = "images/fashion/fpo/25.jpg"
            xoxo[94] = "images/fashion/fpo/26.jpg"
            xoxo[95] = "images/fashion/fpo/27.jpg"
            xoxo[96] = "images/fashion/fpo/28.jpg"
            xoxo[97] = "images/fashion/fpo/29.jpg"
            xoxo[98] = "images/fashion/fpo/30.jpg"
            xoxo[99] = "images/fashion/fpo/31.jpg"
            xoxo[100] = "images/fashion/fpo/32.jpg"
            xoxo[101] = "images/fashion/fpo/33.jpg"
            xoxo[102] = "images/fashion/fpo/34.jpg"
            xoxo[103] = "images/fashion/fpo/35.jpg"
            xoxo[104] = "images/fashion/fpo/36.jpg"
            xoxo[105] = "images/fashion/fpo/37.jpg"
            xoxo[106] = "images/fashion/fpo/38.jpg"
            xoxo[107] = "images/fashion/fpo/39.jpg"
            xoxo[108] = "images/fashion/fpo/40.jpg"
            xoxo[109] = "images/fashion/fpo/41.jpg"
            xoxo[110] = "images/fashion/fpo/42.jpg"
            xoxo[111] = "images/fashion/fpo/43.jpg"
            xoxo[112] = "images/fashion/fpo/44.jpg"
            xoxo[113] = "images/fashion/fpo/45.jpg"
            xoxo[114] = "images/fashion/fpo/46.jpg"
            xoxo[115] = "images/fashion/fpo/47.jpg"
            xoxo[116] = "images/fashion/fpo/48.jpg"
            xoxo[117] = "images/fashion/fpo/49.jpg"
            xoxo[118] = "images/fashion/fpo/50.jpg"
            xoxo[119] = "images/fashion/fpo/51.jpg"
            xoxo[120] = "images/fashion/fpo/52.jpg"
            xoxo[121] = "images/fashion/fpo/53.jpg"
            xoxo[122] = "images/fashion/fpo/54.jpg"
            xoxo[123] = "images/fashion/fpo/55.jpg"
            xoxo[124] = "images/fashion/fpo/56.jpg"
            xoxo[125] = "images/fashion/fpo/57.jpg"
            xoxo[126] = "images/fashion/fpo/58.jpg"
            xoxo[127] = "images/fashion/fpo/59.jpg"
            xoxo[128] = "images/fashion/fpo/60.jpg"
            xoxo[129] = "images/fashion/fpo/61.jpg"
            xoxo[130] = "images/fashion/fpo/62.jpg"
            xoxo[131] = "images/fashion/fpo/63.jpg"
            xoxo[132] = "images/fashion/fpo/64.jpg"
            xoxo[133] = "images/fashion/fpo/65.jpg"
            xoxo[134] = "images/fashion/fpo/66.jpg"
            xoxo[135] = "images/fashion/fpo/67.jpg"
            xoxo[136] = "images/fashion/fpo/68.jpg"
            xoxo[137] = "images/fashion/fpo/69.jpg"
            xoxo[138] = "images/children/fpo/01.jpg"
            xoxo[139] = "images/children/fpo/02.jpg"
            xoxo[140] = "images/children/fpo/03.jpg"
            xoxo[141] = "images/children/fpo/04.jpg"
            xoxo[142] = "images/children/fpo/05.jpg"
            xoxo[143] = "images/children/fpo/06.jpg"
            xoxo[144] = "images/children/fpo/07.jpg"
            xoxo[145] = "images/children/fpo/08.jpg"
            xoxo[146] = "images/children/fpo/09.jpg"
            xoxo[147] = "images/children/fpo/10.jpg"
            xoxo[148] = "images/children/fpo/11.jpg"
            xoxo[149] = "images/children/fpo/12.jpg"
            xoxo[150] = "images/children/fpo/13.jpg"
            xoxo[151] = "images/children/fpo/14.jpg"
            xoxo[152] = "images/children/fpo/15.jpg"
            xoxo[153] = "images/children/fpo/16.jpg"
            xoxo[154] = "images/children/fpo/17.jpg"
            xoxo[155] = "images/children/fpo/18.jpg"
            xoxo[156] = "images/children/fpo/19.jpg"
            xoxo[157] = "images/children/fpo/20.jpg"
            xoxo[158] = "images/children/fpo/21.jpg"
            xoxo[159] = "images/children/fpo/22.jpg"
            xoxo[160] = "images/children/fpo/23.jpg"
            xoxo[161] = "images/children/fpo/24.jpg"
            xoxo[162] = "images/children/fpo/25.jpg"
            xoxo[163] = "images/children/fpo/26.jpg"
            xoxo[164] = "images/children/fpo/27.jpg"
            xoxo[165] = "images/children/fpo/28.jpg"
            xoxo[166] = "images/children/fpo/29.jpg"
            xoxo[167] = "images/children/fpo/30.jpg"
            xoxo[168] = "images/children/fpo/31.jpg"
            xoxo[169] = "images/children/fpo/32.jpg"
            xoxo[170] = "images/children/fpo/33.jpg"
            xoxo[171] = "images/children/fpo/34.jpg"
            xoxo[172] = "images/children/fpo/35.jpg"
            xoxo[173] = "images/children/fpo/36.jpg"
            xoxo[174] = "images/children/fpo/37.jpg"

    function pickRandom(range) {
        if (Math.random)
            return Math.round(Math.random() * (range-1));
        else {
            var now = new Date();
            return (now.getTime() / 1000) % range;
        }
    }
    // Write out an IMG tag, using a randomly-chosen image name.
    var choice = pickRandom(xoxo.length);
    // -->
    </script>
```

```
    <div class="menu">

            <a style="color:#000000" href="index.html">Index</a><br>
            <a href="portrait/overview.html">Portrait</a><br>
            <a href="fashion/overview.html">Fashion</a><br>
            <a href="children/overview.html">Children</a><br>
            <a href="clients.html">Clients</a><br>
            <a href="contact.html">Contact</a><br>

    </div>

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
    <tr valign="middle"><td align="center">

            <a href="index.html"><script type="text/javascript">document.writeln('<img src="'+xoxo[choice]+'" >');</script></a>

    </td></tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Shuffle the array and iterate over it or keep an index and increment it. Maintaing the state across page refreshes is a bit more tricky though. You could use `localStorage` to store the shuffled array but that would not work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JavaScript numbers can hold integers of over 50 bits, 3 numbers could keep track of 150 files.

The following code provides functions for creating, manipulating and interrogating a data structure consisting of an array of 50 bit numbers:

```
function Set (len) {
  // Establish an array of sufficient 50 bit numbers to hold len bits
  this.bits = new Array (Math.floor ((len + 49) / 50));
  this.len = len;
  // Clear all numbers
  for (var i = this.bits.length; i--;)
    this.bits[i] = 0;
}

Set.prototype.full = function () {
  // Check if all bits of the set at 1
  // First check the relevant bits of the last word
  if (this.bits[this.bits.length - 1] === Math.pow (2, this.len + 1) - 1)
    // Then chec tat all remaining numbers are full
    for (var i = this.bits.length - 1; i--;)
      if (bits[i] !== Math.pow (2, 51) - 1)
        return false;
  return true;
}

Set.prototype.check = function (n) {
  // Return value (0 or 1) of bit n of the set
  var m = n % 50; 
  return Math.floor (this.bits [(n - m) / 50] / Math.pow (2, m)) & 1;
}

Set.prototype.add = function (n) {
  // Set bit n of the set to 1 (unless it is already 1)
  if (!this.check (n)) {
    var m = n % 50; 
    this.bits [(n - m) / 50] += Math.pow (2, m);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

Set.prototype.remove = function (n) {
  // Set bit of the set to 0 (unless it is already 0)
  if (this.check (n)) {
    var m = n % 50; 
    this.bits [(n - m) / 50] -= Math.pow (2, m);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

Set.prototype.clear = function () {
  // Clear all bitsof the set to 0 
  for (var i = this.bits.length; i--;)
    bits[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Does this work with my existing script or in place of it?

Comment: My code provides only the functions to manage a boolean set. You also need the code to use those functions and to save the set values in cookies. See here http://jsfiddle.net/bVHMJ/2/

Comment: The names in the file array seem to be incorrect : extra spaces. Did you check your JS console for error messages? Also remove the first script block, it is no longer necessary.

Comment: We need to take this offline. I have created a chat room "HBP and D Benway" meet me there.

Comment: Thanks for your continued attention to this. I tried to join the chat but don't have enough reputation credits to. I do have cookies enabled on my system. The code does work fairly well. What I find is that it consistently repeats 2-3 images out of the 10 before all have been viewed. It would be great to reduce those instances but it's working better than everything else I've tried.

Comment: I have made some significant changes, see http://jsfiddle.net/jstoolsmith/R7NbG/ : tested and working under Chrome browser on Ubuntu. Use my email there to continue our dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

If you really wanted to make sure an image is never repeated until all of them have been shown, you can store a list of indices you have already displayed using `localstorage`.

You can use

```
localStorage['viewedItems'] = JSON.stringify(viewedItems)
```

to save an array to `localstorage`, where viewedItems (the second one) is the name of the array containing all of the indices you have already shown. You can then use

```
JSON.parse(localStorage['viewedItems'])
```

to retrieve the array on every page load to see what you've already displayed. Every time, you're reading it, adding an index (pick an index until you get one not in this array), writing it. Once the size of the array has reached the number of images you have, clear it and start over.

**Updated, and hopefully more detailed, explanation**

First you want to load the `viewedItems` array from `localStorage`. Then pick a random number as you already do, and see if that number exists in `viewedItems`. You can do this using [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). The select a number and check if exists code will be in a loop so you keep doing it until you find a number that doesn't exist in your array. Show that index. You can then use the [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method to add this index to your `viewedItems` array. Finally, save the `viewedItems` array to `localStorage`.

**Pseudocode**

```
load viewedItems from localStorage

do
    r = random number
while viewedItems.indexOf(r) > -1

show xoxo[r]

viewedItems.push(r)

save viewedItems to localStorage
```

Comment: So far, this is the only answer that considers that the OP wants to keep state **between requests**.

Comment: Thanks sachleen. Can you show me how to implement this functionality on my page?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer with some details and pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but give it a spin. Have a second array just as big as the first, but have it store booleans. The indexes from the second array correspond to the indexes from the first array. So when the script gives 24 as the random number, it should return the 25th image from the `xoxo` array, AND it should set the 25th element in the second array to false. For example:

```
// assume isAvailable is the array that holds the bools
function pickRandom(range) {
        checkAvailabilities(); // checks to see if all the images have been used
        if (Math.random) {
           while (true) {
               var choice = Math.round(Math.random() * (range-1));
               if (isAvailable[choice]) {
                  isAvailable[choice] = false;
                  return choice;
               }
           }
        }
        else {
            var now = new Date();
            return (now.getTime() / 1000) % range;
        }
}

function checkAvailabilities()
{
   // check if there are still some images that haven't been chosen
   for (var i = 0; i < isAvailable.length; i++)
      if (isAvailable[i])
         return; 
   // all the images have been used, so make all of them available again
   for (var i = 0; i < isAvailable.length; i++)
      isAvailable[i] = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes some sense to me. I'm not sure what the array that holds the booleans would look like though. Something like this maybe: var isAvailable = new Array(); // Array to hold booleans ... isAvailable[0] = "(not sure what goes here)" ... etc.?

Comment: Well, `isAvailable` tells you which images are available, and since you haven't used any at the start of the script, they're ALL available, and so all would be true.

Comment: Okay, but I must have to create an array called isAvailable. Each item in the xoxo array points to an image location. What would the items in the isAvailble array point to and how would I write that? Also, do I have to call any function in the body of the page for isAvailable to work?

Comment: `isAvailable` is just an array of bools, they aren't located anywhere special. and all you have to do is call `isAvailable` as I've shown above. Every time you call the `pickRandom()` function, `isAvailable` will be updated too. The one thing I have NOT included is initializing `isAvailable`, but that should be easy enough.